# What’s the steepest possible descent for big commercial jets?

Tags: aircraft-performance, commercial-operations

What’s the highest descent rate, an A320/737/A380/younameit can achieve in safe controlled flight and how do they achieve it? E.g. can those jets do side slips to have a steep approach angle (maybe not for final) if they need to land ASAP, for example for a medical emergency / rapid descent due to pressurization problems?